# What is the Latin term for animals which dust bathe?

Tags: zoology, terminology

I have lost track of this term. I am sure that I encountered a Latin word (not a taxonomic word) which applies to all animals which dust bathe.

I fact, I am not even sure how to describe a word like this, cutting across species.

Comment: There are some words like _pulverulent (adj.)_, _Pulveratores (n.)_, _pulveratrix (n.)_ (based on Latin  _pulver-_ , _pulvis_ meaning dust, sand, pulver) but _OED_ gives them as obsolete and rare. They are ornithology terms to define birds that use dust bathing as a means of feather maintenance.

Comment: Thanks, that must have been the word I saw, I think.